# Аутентификация ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, cookie, asp.net-core-mvc, аутентификация

При аутентификации в ASP.NET Core на основе куки или при использовании Identity на клиенте сохраняются куки и передаются с каждым запросом к серверу. При этом если удалить пользователя из БД, куки остаются валидны, и пользователь продолжает иметь доступ к ресурсу. В связи с этим есть следующие вопросы для понимания механизма аутентификации:

1. Когда пользователю выдаются куки, что происходит на сервере? Такие же куки сохраняются на сервере? Где? Можно ли их посмотреть?
2. Как происходит валидация кук? Как я понимаю, куки из запроса пользователя каким-то образом (каким?) проверяются на наличие на сервере. Если есть, то доступ разрешен. Если на сервере нет соответствующих кук (или в запросе от клиента нет кук), то доступ запрещен.
3. Можно ли при удалении пользователя из БД удалить соответствующую куку на сервере? Тогда пользователь пошлет запрос, в запросе будут выданные ранее куки, но они будут отсутствовать на сервере, и доступ будет запрещен.
4. Как можно принудительно разлогинить всех пользователей? Можно ли как-то удалить все записи о залогиненных пользователях?
5. При настройке времени жизни кук таким образом:

   ```
           services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
           .AddCookie(options => 
           {
               options.LoginPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/Authentication/Login");
               options.AccessDeniedPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/Authentication/AccessDenied");
               options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
           });
   ```

   кука в браузере все равно обозначена как сессионная. При этом по прошествии указанного времени доступ закрывается и нужно снова логиниться. Почему?

Comment: https://wakeupandcode.com/cookies-and-consent-in-asp-net-core/